# Win32: How do I get the listbox for a combobox

Tags: winapi, combobox, listbox

I'm writing some code and I need to get the window handle of the listbox associated with a combo box.  When looking in spy++, it looks like the parent of the listbox is the desktop, not the combo box.  How can I programmatically find the listbox window handle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Send [`CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775839%28VS.85%29.aspx) to the combo box, and it fills in a [`COMBOBOXINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775798%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) structure, which contains the window handles to the edit control and the list box control.